# How do I fix expected identifier error in c?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to prompt the user for a number between 1-8 and reprompt if they don't respond correctly. However when I try to compile my code I get these errors.

```
mario.c:4:15: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
int main(void)
              ^
              ;
mario.c:6:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
2 errors generated.
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
int height;
{
    do
    {
        height = get_int ("Enter Height: ");
    } 
    while (height > 8 || <1);
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you invest in a decent beginners book. One made this century so you don't mistake pre-standard argument declarations with local variable definitions.

Comment: You forgot a brace after `int main(void)`. The compiler assumed you meant to only declare `main` (not define it), in which case you'd have forgotten the semicolon after `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opening bracket should be directly after `main`, not after `height` is declared.

Also `while(height >8 || <1)` should be `while(height >8 || height <1)`.

```
int main(void){
  int height;
  do
  {
    height = get_int("Enter Height: ");
  }
  while(height >8 || height<1);
}
```